# Switch from Wifi to mobile data while roaming

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, roaming

We use international SIM cards in our our standard Android phones (SAMSUNG XCover4s). When they opperate in a weak Wifi environment, we would like them to be supported by the mobile data connection or even switch to the mobile data connection (even though its on roaming), so my question is:

Is there a way to **activate the "Switch to mobile data"** option in the "intellegent Wifi" option of Android (10), **when the device is roaming**?

We have full access to the devices. Android Version 10.

Thanks for any help/hint.

Unfortunately I only have the screenshot in German:
[image]

Comment: According to the gsmarena database this device only has Android 9/10, "current" would be Android 11. So which version do you really have?

Comment: Automate app from Llama labs has a feature to detect if the phone is in roaming. There is also the option to check signal strength of Wifi. You can use them to turn wifi off or on. But you have to always have mobile data enabled because Automate app cannot toggle mobile data without root access.

Comment: True, Robert, it is Android 10. I updated the description.
@Firelord: Thanks for pointing me to that app - it looks promising. Our issue is that the wifi is availiable (wifi strength is good) put the internet connection is slow/bad. I just did update the description of my question. I will try the "Network throughput" and "ping" block. Thanks